# matplotlib 2.0 changing axes fontsize and legend fontsize independently

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am making a plot where I need the axes title font to be slightly larger than the legend font. I haven't been able to achieve this. I am using a style file and have tried : axes.titlesize , legend.fontsize and font.size (which changes both). However, they don't seem to give the desired behaviour.

How can i set the font size for each independently, for example in the below code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy

#plt.style.use("myStyle.mplstyle.py")

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xs = scipy.linspace(0,1,100)
ys1 = scipy.sin(xs)
ys2 = scipy.cos(xs)

ax.plot(xs, ys1,"-",label="sin")
ax.plot(xs, ys2,"-",label="cos")
ax.set_xlabel("this is the title axis")
ax.set_ylabel("this is the title axis 2")
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The available style settings can be viewed on the [customization page](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html)

- `axes.titlesize` changes the fontsize of the title
- `axes.labelsize` changes the fontsize of the x- and y- label
- `legend.fontsize` changes the fontsize of the legend

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy

plt.rcParams["axes.titlesize"] = 18
plt.rcParams["legend.fontsize"] = 8
plt.rcParams["axes.labelsize"] = 12

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
xs = scipy.linspace(0,1,100)
ys1 = scipy.sin(xs)
ys2 = scipy.cos(xs)
ax.set_title("Title")
ax.plot(xs, ys1,"-",label="sin")
ax.plot(xs, ys2,"-",label="cos")
ax.set_xlabel("this is the title axis")
ax.set_ylabel("this is the title axis 2")
ax.legend()

plt.show()
```

[image]